# Return a certain index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below, where the function getImageNum recieves an array with urls concatenated, so I split these urls on a symbol, so that I can get them separated.
My variable res = path.split("-") holds the separated urls. So res[0] gives for example an url that looks like this: http://www.host.net/dir/file.
But my problem is that I want to get every url in the res var, so that I can use it in a slide show. So instead of res[0], I wanna be able to use a variable that retains the different indexes automatically. See the code below for the idea.

```
function getImageNum(imageArray) { 
var path;
var res;
var index = 0;

for (i in imageArray) {
    path = imageArray[i];
}

res = path.split("-");

$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_imageView").attr("src", res[index++]);
}
```

The code:

```
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_imageView").attr("src", res[index++]);
```

just returns the same image, and does not go through the entire res contents

Comment: how do you want the slide show to work... like change the image every two seconds

Comment: can you please make a fiddle?

Comment: I already have written the code that makes the slide, this changes images every 5th second. I just need to add the url to the src attribute, then the slide will take care of showing the images

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i in imageArray) {
    path = imageArray[i];
}
```

This code is going to loop through each image in `imageArray` and then overwrite `path` to the latest image each time.  If you want to append more text to the path rather than completely replacing it every loop you need to concat.  However, it looks like all you want to to store an array of all paths in your `res` variable, so why even bother with the string?

```
for (i in imageArray) {
    res.push(imageArray[i]);
}
```

Second, `index++` does not automagically iterate through all index's, it is only an operator that increments the value after it gives you its old value.  You are going to have to manually loop through each image in `res` if you want all of the images.

Comment: At the time you say: res.push(imageArray[i]); the you only have a long string of concatenated urls. So I need to split them. The code that I have so works, but maybe it's only in this situation that it works.
The issue is the how to pass it to the src attribute so that it adds the urls to the src attribute

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, 'cause it's not exactly clear, you have a problem with the loops
As it was said before by Lochemage, doing stuff **outside** the *for loop* with a variable that gets its value **inside** the *for loop*, will not work.

```
var imageArray = ["http://www.example.com/img1-http://www.example.com/img2-http://www.example.com/img3-http://www.example.com/img4","http://www.example.com/img5-http://www.example.com/img6-http://www.example.com/img7-http://www.example.com/img8-http://www.example.com/img9"];
// this is what I assume is your array
var imageArrayNew = [];

for(i=0; i<imageArray.length; i++) {
    res = imageArray[i].split("-");
    for(j=0; j<res.length; j++) {
        imageArrayNew.push(res[j]);
    }
}

// now imageArrayNew is an array that contains Each of the elements in imageArray and you can do stuff with it
```

http://jsfiddle.net/flish/U5vvv/ - the fiddle to how it looks

---

edited to delete an extra "-"